# how to stop refreshing page in delphi intraweb onchange?

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-2010, intraweb

I made a form with 100+ TIWComboBox questions on one page.

Using the OnChange event, the page is updated on every response. That is an inconvenience when we are at the end of the Form because it returns to the beginning every time it responds.

Is there any code that solves this problem? (Ps. I would not want to use Async events).

Best regards

I used Async, but it didn't work. I wanted to find a code to stop going up the page.

Comment: A form with 100+ input fields sounds rather much. Splitting up the form into several smaller forms is not an option?

Comment: Why OnAsyncChange doesn't work? This event should not refresh the page giving you the chance to manage the "onchange" JavaScript event.